# Removing a backslash "\" when passing arguments to newcommand

Tags: macros, spacing

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\NewS}[4]{
    % Q1: How can I use argument #1 without the backslash in the following line?
    \newglossaryentry{symb:#4}{
        name=\ensuremath{#2},
        description={\nopostdesc #3}, 
        sort=sym#4,
    }

    % Q2: Why is the space between the '}' necessary?
    \def#1{\ensuremath{#2} } 
}

\NewS{\power}{P}{the power of something}{power}

\begin{document}
    One can refer to the symbol via \power and \gls{symb:power} and. 
\end{document}
```

The two questions I have are already inserted in the example. In particular I am searching for a way to remove the backlash of the string `\power` which I pass as a first argument to the `newcommand` so that I can write something like:

```
\newglossaryentry{symb:WITHOUT_BACKSLASH(#1)}{
```

And secondly I don't understand why I have to leave a space between the two braces in the `\def` in order to get "P and" in the output and not "Pand" - which is what I get when I remove the space. If I directly write `\ensuremath{P} and` I don't see any problems so I am just curious.

Thanks for your help!

Regards

Comment: Related Question: [How to extract the name of a macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100542/how-to-extract-the-name-of-a-macro).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how you need to use the control sequence name. A method for *printing* the control sequence name without the backslash is

```
\begingroup\escapechar=-1\edef\x{\endgroup\string\power}\x
```

In a definition, the explicit `\power` will be `#1`. But, again, it depends on what you want to do with the string.

The second question is a very frequently asked one: TeX ignores spaces after control sequence names like `\power`. Don't put a space in the definition, but rather write `\power{}` in the document.

If you just want to spare an argument, then use the LaTeX kernel function

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\NewS}[3]{%
    \newglossaryentry{symb:#1}{
        name=\ensuremath{#2},
        description={\nopostdesc #3}, 
        sort=sym#1,
    }%
    \@namedef{#1}{\ensuremath{#2}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Now `\NewS{power}{P}{the power of something}` will suffice and you will be able to say

```
\begin{document}
One can refer to the symbol via \power{} and \gls{symb:power} and. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding the second question: I thought that `\power` is treated like a string when I use it as an argument of a command, e.g. in `\NewS{\power}{...}` above and that I can access this string via `#1` in the definition of the command `\NewS`. Thus I understand `\def#1{something}` as `\def\power{something}`. I was therefore looking for a way to use the string without the backslash in the line `\newglossaryentry{symb:<insert string 'power' here>}{`. But I think that Ians answer is the better way to go.

Comment: To avoid the `{}` everytime you use `\power`, you could include the `{xspace}` package, add `\xspace` to the end of the defintition of `\power`, and then use it as `The \power is the \power.` and should have a space before the **is** but not before the period.

Comment: Another option (which is slightly shorter and I think better because it doesn't look like it is passing an empty argument to a macro) is to use `\ `—that is, a backslash followed by a space (or new line)— after `\power`: `...via \power\ and ...`.

Answer (score 7):

In `expl3`, there is a `\cs_to_str:N` function to get the macro name without a backslash.
If you are not familar with `expl3` syntax, you can define a clone of the function:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \let\cstostr\cs_to_str:N
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\cstostr\foobar
% We obtain: foobar
\end{document}
```

Note: `\cs_to_str:N` is fully expandable. Thus it's robust enough.

It's nontrivial to define a command like `\cs_to_str:N`. You can check the definition in [`source3`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/source3.pdf) document, if you want to pry.

Here is my version of `\cstostr`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\cstostr#1{%
  \expandafter\@gobble\detokenize\expandafter{\string#1}}
\makeatother
```

The definition is much simpler than LaTeX3's `\cs_to_str:N`, but may fail when `\escapechar` is unusual. It is also fully expandable.

---

TeX ignores all spaces after a all-letter macro by default. To solve the question about space, you can use:

```
\power\ and
```

or

```
\power{} and
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach is to create the macro from the string.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\newcommand\makemacro[1]{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{arnold}}
\begin{document}
\makemacro{power}
\power
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. And it seems to be the more natural approach.