# Extract multiplier from siunitx prefix

Tags: siunitx

Is there a way to extract the multiplication factor that each `siunitx` prefix represents. Basically, can I automate `ExplainPrefix` to correctly produce the correct output.  Current output uses `x` as the exponent:

[image]

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{expl3}

%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100542/how-to-extract-the-name-of-a-macro
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\CsToStr}[1]{\cs_to_str:N #1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\ExplainPrefix}[1]{%
\par
The prefix \CsToStr{#1} (symbol: \si{#1}) representes multiplication by $10^x$.
}%

\DeclareSIPrefix\wacky{X}{41}

\begin{document}

\ExplainPrefix{\kilo}
\ExplainPrefix{\micro}
\ExplainPrefix{\wacky}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for

```
\si[prefixes-as-symbols = false]{#1}
```

which will convert the prefix symbol to the value (a single stand-alone prefix is allowed here: I plan in figure to introduce some kind of 'no-op' unit to make the logic a bit easier).

The data for this conversion is stored in the internal property list `\l__siunitx_prefix_forward_prop`, which may of course change in the future but is there if you want to do something more complex.