# List of Unused \newbox, \newcount, \newdimen, \newskip, etc

Tags: boxes, counters, dimensions

Want a *appropriate command* to list out unused `Box`, `Counter`, `Dimension`, `Skip` from the **CLS/STY** file.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit? I'm not sure what you are after: if you do `\newbox\mybox` some box register number is associated with `\mybox` globally, so we can't know it's 'not used'.

Comment: I have lots of `\newbox` declared in my **CLS** file, most of those are not assigned. And its very difficult to find the unused (`\newbox` alone found more than 50, hardly 10-20 `\newbox` used)...

Comment: Expected Command like `\listfiles` (which provides the list of files used), if any...

Comment: why do you want this list? there are over 32 thousand boxes (in etex based formats) so if you have 50 unused does it matter?, and how can you tell if it is unused? the normal case would be for it to be declared in the class but used in a document.

Comment: IMHO the easist way is to use your editor search (find) `\mybox` if only one occurrence the box (register) is not used or you can use a script.

Comment: @David: my CLS and supporting STY files having thousands of declaration for `\newbox, \newdimen, \newcount`. I used `etex` package to extend the allocation. I presume that too much of unused boxes, may lack of speed during compilation, correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @touhami: If no option found then I need to use a script.

Comment: @KumareshPS Does "my CLS and supporting STY files" mean written by you? Or they are standard ones?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke: Written by many developers.

Comment: an unused \newbox has no affect on _anything_  (other than the space taken up for a command name). All it does is assign that name to be a _number_ the numbered box register is there all the time, there are a fixed number of them. You should not be using the etex package these days latex will allocate into the extended range by default. Really you have _thousands_ of box allocations??? what are you doing, I don't think I have seen a class that has more than a dozen or so??????

Comment: Please consider with other commands `\newcount`, `\newskip`, `\newdimen` too... Everywhere find these commands and most of them are untouched anywhere in class... Good to know these commands wont make any trouble in the performance...

Comment: You can easily get such a list using grep or any editor, but why does your class allocate registers that it doesn't use? why did anyone write `\newcount\foo` into the class if they neither use `\foo` nor document that a user of the class can use it? If you really have thousands of allocations, something seems to be very wrong with the code.

Comment: a make a loop with 5000 `\newbox, \newcount, \newskip, \newdimen` it compile normally.

Comment: @KumareshPS: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. I am not sure about the general case, but if there is a clear way that you are using them, then it simply a matter of redefining `\newbox` (in DEBUG mode) to add to a list, and redefine `\savebox` to add to another list of boxes that get used, and then at the end output this list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the question appears to be about the resources taken up by register allocations it should be noted that despite the names `\newbox`, `\newcount` etc do not generate new box or count registers.

There are 256 or 32768 or 65536 registers of each type available (depending on the engine). These are available *all the time* whether or not you allocate anything.

```
\count600=42
```

sets count register 600 to 42 and doesn't need you to allocate 600 registers with `\newcount`.

```
\newcount\mycount
```

or

```
\newbox\mybox
```

just declare `\newcount` or `\newbox` to be a *number* associated to the register (in the case of `\newbox` just using `\chardef` usually.)

So the only extra resource of having unused `\newcount` is like the resource of `\let\myname\@empty` of the space taken up to store the commandname itself, and its association to the register.

in etex and xetex there is the theoretical issue that the first 256 "classical" registers are stored more efficiently than the extended registers (which are stored as a sparse array) but on modern machines this is unlikely to make any observable difference, and isn't an issue in luatex at all, which stores the full set of 65536 registers in the same way.

If you always access the registers via non-expandable macros, those macros could be extended to log usage, but in general this is not possible, if you have a usage like

```
\newcount\mycount
...
\typeout{\the\mycount}
```

Then it is unlikely that you can log the usage of `\mycount` from within tex in any reliable way. It is of course easy just to search for `\mycount` in your source files in an editor or using sed or perl etc, so that is likely to be the most reliable method.

If your class files have lots of unused register allocations (or even lots of register allocations that are used) then there is something very strange in the code, very few classes have more than ten or so such allocations.

Comment: It's very kind of you for the brief explanation...

Comment: The "just declare..." part seems to be a body text, not a code to me. I leave a comment here because I couldn't submit such a tiny edit.

Comment: Performed this by using script...

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of how to locate any unused `\newbox`. The MWE below defines three boxes:

```
\newbox{\MyBoxA}
\newbox{\MyBoxB}
\newbox{\MyBoxC}
```

but only box `\MyBoxB` is ever used, so the other two get reported as unused:

[image]

### Notes:

- `\usepackage{debugboxes}` needs to be *before* any `\newbox`.
- If you comment out the `\usepackage{debugboxes}`, then things work as normal, but when that is included, you get the report of unused boxes.
- [The `filecontents` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents)
  was used to package the test case and create the `debugboxes.sty`.
  It is not needed in you actual use case.

---

### Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{debugboxes.sty}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{expl3}

%%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100542/how-to-extract-the-name-of-a-macro
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \newcommand{\CsToStr}[1]{\cs_to_str:N #1}
\ExplSyntaxOff


%% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14393/how-keep-a-running-list-of-strings-and-then-process-them-one-at-a-time
\newcommand\SaveboxList{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AddToSaveboxList}[1]{%
    \g@addto@macro\SaveboxList{#1,}%
}
\makeatother
\let\OldNewBox\newbox
\renewcommand{\newbox}[1]{%
    \AddToSaveboxList{\CsToStr{#1}}%
    \OldNewBox{#1}%
}%

\let\OldUsebox\usebox%
\renewcommand{\usebox}[1]{%
    \csgdef{SaveboxUsed \CsToStr{#1}}{}%
    \OldUsebox{#1}%
}%


\AtEndDocument{%
\bigskip
    \section{Unused saveboxes}%
    \foreach \x in \SaveboxList {%
        \ifcsdef{SaveboxUsed \x}{}{%
            \par\noindent\x
        }%
    }
}%
\end{filecontents*}




\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{debugboxes}% Comment this out if don't need the debugging,

\newbox{\MyBoxA}
\newbox{\MyBoxB}
\newbox{\MyBoxC}


\begin{document}
\savebox{\MyBoxB}{some content placed in box}
\usebox{\MyBoxB}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, this is easily defeated if the class/package says `\box\whatever` instead of `\usebox{\whatever}`. Such an usage would cause a false positive.

Comment: @egreg: Yep, hence my request in the comments as to a MWE that shows how things are used.  This was just meant as an example of how things might be done. Not intended as a general solution to work in all cases.