# Wacky Behaviour for \csdef

Tags: conditionals, expl3, brackets, etoolbox

I am using `\csdef{}` to define a meaning to a given open/close bracket:

```
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{\lvert}}{Left |}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{\rvert}}{Right |}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{(}}{open (}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{)}}{close )}
```

The first two and the last *seem* to work just fine, but the third one has an issue. When I attempt to access these via `#1~\csuse{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{#1}}` (where `#1` is one of the four given brackets `\lvert`, `\rvert`, `(` and `)`, the output is:

[image]

I had expected the one highlighted in red to be `( open (`.

So, what is going on here, and how should I restructure this to obtain the desired result for the `(` bracket?

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%% Following package not needed with newer binaries
\usepackage{expl3}%    \cs_to_str:N

\ExplSyntaxOn
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100543/4301
    \newcommand{\CsToStr}[1]{\cs_to_str:N #1}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{\lvert}}{Left |}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{\rvert}}{Right |}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{(}}{open (}% FAILS !!
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{)}}{close )}

\newcommand{\ShowBracketMeaning}[1]{%
    #1~
    \ifcsdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{#1}}{%
        \csuse{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{#1}}%
     }{\text{No Meaning Defined}}%
}%

\begin{document}
$\ShowBracketMeaning{\lvert}$

$\ShowBracketMeaning{\rvert}$

{\color{red}%
    $\ShowBracketMeaning{(}$% <---- ????? This should show "open ("
}

$\ShowBracketMeaning{)}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try

```
\edef\test{\CsToStr{(}}
\show\test
```

you'll see that the answer is

```
> \test=macro:
->.
```

The `\cs_to_str:N` function should *only* be applied to control sequences; otherwise its result is unpredictable (well, it is predictable, but not what you seem to want to get anyway).

Since both `\CsToStr{(}` and `\CsToStr{)}` return empty, the second definition involving them overrides the first.

Solution: if you *really* want that, don't use `\CsToStr`:

```
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{\lvert}}{Left |}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{\rvert}}{Right |}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning (}{open (}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning )}{close )}
```

On the other hand, you don't need to remove the backslash when you form a control sequence, as long as the backslash is “other”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TokenToStr}{m}{\token_to_str:N #1}%
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\csdefinedTF}{mmm}
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{Bracket Meaning \TokenToStr{\lvert}}{Left |}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{Bracket Meaning \TokenToStr{\rvert}}{Right |}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{Bracket Meaning \TokenToStr{(}}{open (}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{Bracket Meaning \TokenToStr{)}}{close )}

\newcommand{\ShowBracketMeaning}[1]{%
    #1~
    \csdefinedTF{Bracket Meaning \TokenToStr{#1}}{%
        \UseName{Bracket Meaning \TokenToStr{#1}}%
     }{\text{No Meaning Defined}}%
}

\begin{document}

$\ShowBracketMeaning{\lvert}$

$\ShowBracketMeaning{\rvert}$

$\ShowBracketMeaning{(}$

$\ShowBracketMeaning{)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, is there a `\ifControlSequence{}` equivalent macro that I can use in `\ShowBracketMeaning` to determine if I am going to use `\csuse{Bracket Meaning \CsToStr{#1}}` or `\csuse{Bracket Meaning #1}`

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm not sure what your purpose is, but there's the conditional `\token_if_cs:NTF`, so you can branch. And I'd avoid mixing `expl3` with `etoolbox`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I added a slightly different approach that requires no branching.

Comment: Works great (not that there was any doubt). Thanks. I assume `\UseName` is just a `\csuse{}`?  I also found using `\detokenize{}` yields the desired results, but wondering if there is a problem with that approach.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yes, `\UseName` is the kernel version of `\csuse`. About `\detokenize`, it's `\tl_to_str:n` in `expl3`, for multiple tokens, whereas `\token_to_str:N` is for a single token.

Answer (score 2):

Befor egreg posted the detailed solution, I found that using `\detokenize{}` instead of relying on `\CsToStr{}` yields the desired results.

Am posting this to see in case there are any issues that I am not aware of with this approach.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\csdef{Bracket Meaning \detokenize{\lvert}}{Left |}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \detokenize{\rvert}}{Right |}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \detokenize{(}}{open (}
\csdef{Bracket Meaning \detokenize{)}}{close )}

\newcommand{\ShowBracketMeaning}[1]{%
    #1~
    \ifcsdef{Bracket Meaning \detokenize{#1}}{%
        \csuse{Bracket Meaning \detokenize{#1}}%
     }{\text{No Meaning Defined}}%
}%

\begin{document}
$\ShowBracketMeaning{\lvert}$

$\ShowBracketMeaning{\rvert}$

$\ShowBracketMeaning{(}$

$\ShowBracketMeaning{)}$
\end{document}
```