# Creating a csname from a macro

Tags: etoolbox

Say I have a macro `\bob` and that macro is passed to another macro as an argument:

```
\makemacro{\bob}
```

I want `\makemacro` to create another macro, based on the name of the passed macro, say `\bob@two`.

This is easy with etoolbox if I passed a csname (just "bob") and not a macro:

```
\cslet{#1@two}{...}
```

but if I'm passed a macro, this of course doesn't work:

```
\letcs#1@two{...}
```

I have a feeling there is painfully obvious way of doing this but I can't see it.

EDIT: I found an answer here: [Removing a backslash "\" when passing arguments to newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20456/removing-a-backslash-when-passing-arguments-to-newcommand)

Comment: Did you try: `\csletcs`

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using but I need to turn the macro into a csname first ...